# cakephp passedArgs empty

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple form in a a view and I am trying to access the $this=>passedArgs but it is coming back empty.

I am actualy trying to use the cakeDC search plugin which uses the $this=>passedArgs. It must be something simple I have not done to get the results from the form submit.

find view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Member', array(
    'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'find'), $this->params['pass'])
));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('div' => false));
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search'), array('div' => false));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Controller

```
public function find() {
    debug($this->passedArgs);
    exit;
}
```

I have tried $this->request->params

```
array(
 'plugin' => null,
 'controller' => 'members',
 'action' => 'find',
 'named' => array(),
 'pass' => array(),
 'isAjax' => false
)
```

I have add method get to the form.
This question has been asked before but their solution of having lower cases in the public $uses = array('order', 'product'); when it should be public $uses = array('Order', 'Product'); did not work.

**Cakephp version 2.3.5**

Thanks for any help

Update:

I have set my form to method get and this is the url:

```
http://localhost/loyalty/members/find?name=searchtext
```

I have removed the plugin and I still do not get anything $this->passedArgs, but I now get data for $this->request->data['name']. Once I put  public $components = array('Search.Prg'); I get noting again for $this->request->data['name'].

I have tried again $this->Prg->parsedParams() with the Search plugin and I just get array()

Comment: are you using the current dev branch? there have currently been some fixes regarding this. AND - take a look at the readme - it is now adviced to not use passedArgs anymore if possible.

Comment: sorry, where can I get the dev branch, I do not see it on githun, is it labeled as something else?

Comment: just change it with a single click from master to develop - https://github.com/cakedc/search/tree/develop

Comment: ah ok sorry, I miss understood, yes I am using the dev branch of the cakeDC search plugin. I though you were were referring to Cakephp itself :-( Getting tired I think. I have also tried debugging the $this->Prg->parsedParams(), empty also

Comment: What is your exact url after hitting the search button? I bet it is empty (just the index page) - and that is your problem. That you are not searching for anything there. Thus empty passed params.

Comment: aha, that looks pretty screwed up. Are you not using mod_rewrite? You might also not use the plugin as you are supposed to. The url should be `http://localhost/loyalty/members/find?name=tr8324032hgy` etc. The plugin does that for you automatically if you use it the right way.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the url. I screwed up the url. I changed the form method in Firebug to get 'get' then submitted but cakephp remembered that it was set to post so it gave that url. Anyway I do have the correct url. The plugin seems to effect $this->request->data. But when I take the plugin away I get data again. But either way I still get nothing for $this->Prg->parsedParams(). Thanks for the help so far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear on that.
You cannot just debug something that has not been set yet.
So including the plugin itself (and its component) is not enough.

From the readme/documenation:

```
public function find() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = $this->ModelName->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
    $this->set('...', $this->paginate());
}
```

Note the commonProcess() call which then only makes passedArgs contain what you need.

Comment: Yes I have all this, I have uploaded the example here http://treacysgroup.com/loyalty/members/mem_points everything looks fine.

Comment: `Notice (8): Undefined index: Member [APP/Plugin/Search/Controller/Component/PrgComponent.php, line 359]`- You are not properly passing on the posted data. The Member index should not be empty.

Comment: Yes indeed it was a problem with the way I was passing the form data in. I had set the attribute of 'name'=>'Member' which removes the data[Member][member_no] from the input field. Also I had to include the paginator component.